What is the most efficient way to test whether a json object is empty(with out any key/value) in pg?
I am trying to detect whether a json object is empty. My json data varies. Some json data have a number of key/values. so, I think jsonb_object_keys would waste time to build key list. Are there better ways to realize the conceptual function such as "hasAnyKey", "isEmpty"?

JSONB type supports the equality check operator. So here is the simple function.
create or replace function jsonb_is_empty(j jsonb)
returns boolean immutable language sql parallel safe as
$$
 select j = '{}'::jsonb or j = '[]'::jsonb;
$$;

Alternative one (for JSON)
create or replace function json_is_empty(j json)
returns boolean immutable language sql parallel safe as
$$
 select j::jsonb in ('{}', '[]');
$$; 


good, I change column into jsonb
